How to convert int to boolean when deserializing into a protobuf object in Java?
I'm trying to deserialize a JSON string (from a http request body) into a protobuf object in Java using the com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat class:
JsonFormat.parser().ignoringUnknownFields().merge(new InputStreamReader(requestBody), builder);

The problem is that I'm using an existing protobuf message definition where some fields have been defined as bool while the JSON I'm receiving has these fields as either 0 or 1. When trying to deserialize, this results in exception with the following message: Invalid bool value: 1.
Is there any way to cast 1 and 0 to true and false for a field that has the bool type in the protobuf message definition type when deserializing?

The JSON does not correctly reflect the Protobuf schema. You could preprocess the JSON and correct the number values (1,0) to be JSON Boolean values (true,false) before attempting to use the default JsonFormat parser. Alternatively -- not a Java developer -- you could write a custom parser to handle this conversion.

Your simplest strategy is almost certainly going to be to parse the JSON into a different proto message that stores the fields as integers, and then to explicitly convert between the proto message types.  You are unlikely to be able to change the behavior of the parser.
